# DeleteContents from mailbox with no confirmation (exchange 2010 and powershell)

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

I use the following command to delete the contents of a mailbox, but it still prompts me to confirm. Is there a way to not prompt me.

```
Search-Mailbox -id "UserName" -DeleteContent -Confirm:$false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to stop prompting is to use the `-Force` parameter (if the cmdlet supports it).

Setting `-Confirm` to `$false` just means "prompt me if you need to."  Setting `-Confirm` to `$true` means "prompt me every time."

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a syntax error `-confirm` like `-DeleteContent` is a `SwitchParameter` this means that you just have to omit it.

```
Search-Mailbox -id "UserName" -DeleteContent
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not knowing that.

Answer (score 0):

Simple thing just go through `/Library/Mail/v2/MailData` and delete the files with names 
`Envelope` then all the contents will be deleted from Mail App